# MS DTC or TransactionScope max timeout

Tags: .net, transactionscope, msdtc

I have a question about timeout for distibuted transactions.

Foe example, I have timeout for TransactionScope = 10 minutes (max, without editing machine.config). 
Also timeout for MS DTC is (as i see in ComponentServices-MyComputer properties) is 60 seconds.

Dows anyone know, what timeout will be taken?

Answer (score 1):

that depends: the transaction scope can be a DTC transaction and then you get the 60 second timeout, or it might get implemented as a SQL local transaction (for example) and then DTC isn't part of the picture so you get the timeout you specified.

the implementation of the transaction depends on the resources you access as part of the transaction, and also the flags you pass to the TransactionScope (Full integration with COM+ for instance)